# 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this code that present a gridview that retrieved the data from 2 datasources.
each line present an order details and the last column present the order status.
the order status should be updateable in a dropdownlist .

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="OrderDataSource"
    CssClass="DataTables">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="oID" HeaderText="oId" SortExpression="oId" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOpened" HeaderText="DateOpened" SortExpression="DateOpened"
            ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rName" HeaderText="rName" SortExpression="rName" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfArrival" HeaderText="DateOfArrival" SortExpression="DateOfArrival"
            ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity"
            ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sName" HeaderText="sName" SortExpression="sName" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="osName" SortExpression="osName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="StatusDataSource"
                    DataTextField="osName" DataValueField="osID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("osName") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("osName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrderDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup9_prodConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="spGetOrdersListForProject" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="Update[Orders] set [osID] =@osID where [oID]=@oID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ProjectIDHolder" DefaultValue="" Name="ProjectID"
            PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="osID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="oID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StatusDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup9_prodConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="spGetOrderStatus" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem is that when i'm trying to edit a column in the gridview i get this error: (after i click the edit button)

```
Server Error in '/Maestro' Application.

'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

Answer (score 1):

Error seems clear to me. The values in the DropDownList don't contain the value that you're trying to set as the selected value. This is probably because the values are from the `osID` column and the selected value is from the `osName` column. Whatever the selected value ends up being, it should come from the data source which means you should probably use the same column (or a foreign key relationship).

You should probably change it to...

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("osID") %>'
```

and make sure that `spGetOrdersListForProject` returns the osID.

Comment: but the dropdownlist source is spGetOrderStatus that reutrn osID and osName.
the spGetOrdersListForProject returns :
oID, DateOpened, rName, DateOfArrival, Quantity, sName , osName

Comment: The DropDownList source is spGetOrderStatus but you're using the selected value of osName which doesn't exist as a value. You MUST use osID if that's what the possible values are. Please try it as I showed you, seeing it in action should increase your understanding.